# Update binding before event ValueChanged

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I follow a MVC model in a vb winform app. I have a DatePicker with a ValueChanged event, and a property binded to it.

The problem is this, when the user changes the date, the event is fired and the controller checks the value of the model, which is not updated. After the event is fired, the property is updated.

How can I force an update right before the event is fired?

DataSourceUpdateMode is set to DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

control.DataBindings("PorpertyName").WriteValue() was the method I needed.